# Path to shell executable "d:\VsCode Projects\C\gcc" does not exist

Tags: c, compiler-errors, tdm-gcc

I formated my computer yesterday and reinstalled vscode, the compiler and included it to the path, but the program doesn't generate output, here a screenshot
[image of the code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFjVp.png))
if anyone can help me fix it, it would be very helpful.

I tried restarting vscode, reinstalling c/c++ compile run extension, but didn't work, if anyone can give me a detailed explanation on how to fix this please do.

OS: Windows 11
Compiler: TDM-GCC

Comment: VS Code is simply a code editor/IDE, afaik you need to install a compiler separately. If you've already done that, you'll need to figure out how to tell VS Code where it lives,, in the VS Code Projects folder is doubtful.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: looks promising: https://semicolon.dev/windows/how-to-install-mingw-gcc-g-compiler-windows-10-11-2023

Comment: I already have the MingW-64 with the TDM-GCC, but VScode doesn't let me compile correctly, how do I add the path for the compiler to vscode?

Comment: Nevermind fixed (I had put the wrong path)

Answer (score 0):

If the terminal is not the proble, check the Path settings, copy the path and paste it to vs code, in my case I had the incorrect path and that is why it didn't compile.